# SQL query not working on node but works in pgadmin 4

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I have a sql statement where I select all the column names from the table called take_5. It works in pgadmin 4 and outputs the columns names. When I use the sql query inside of node with the library pg-promise it doesn't work.

```
    router.post("/", function (req, response) {
        let lottoGame = req.body.data;
        db.query('SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = $1:name' [lottoGame])            
        .then(function(data) {
                response.send((data));
        })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error with post: ' + lottoGame);
            })
    });
```

The post function get data from the frontend and saves it to the lottoGame variable. That variable it used to get the game name like take_5. I have used other query before like

```
db.query('SELECT $1:name FROM $2:name', ['*', lottoGame])
```

and they have worked completely fine. I think there is something definitely wrong with the ending of the query statement because in pgadmin 4 the query looks like this with take_5 inside of a parentheses and it doesn't work if take_5(table name) is outside of a parentheses

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'take_5';
```

Comment: Invalid use of filters. Remove `:name` from `WHERE table_name = $1:name`, it's just a value, not a column name.

Comment: I made that change but it sql query still doesn't work. I think it is a name because it is a table name

Comment: Doesn't work how? Please be more specific.

Comment: I took out the :name and the query doesn't pull the information from the database. When I run 
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'take_5';
on pgadmin 4 it pulls the data I need but
db.query('SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = $1' [lottoGame])       
just causes a error and goes to the catch statement
the error is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid query format.

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` can only appear when you fail to handle an error, which means the actual error happens elsewhere, where you are not passing in a valid query to the query method, and not within the example that you showed here.

Comment: the same example I showed above I took out the catch statement to show the error. 
db.query('SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = $1' [lottoGame]) 
The problem is this query because it doesn't work and goes to the catch block
when i use this query 
db.query('SELECT $1:name FROM $2:name', ['*', lottoGame])
the code works fine. 
so I know that the issue lies with the first query I listed above and it probably has to do with the fact that 
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'take_5';
take_5 isn't in parentheses in query